# Import dict that changes after import

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file in my project - settings.py that contains all sorts of configurations such as `x = {}` (a dict that later assigned with an updated value, which I will use here as an example), and these configurations are imported all over the code to be used by various business logic.

In main.py (which is where everything starts) I create a listener that listens to events and once triggered, it sets `settings.x = {different dict}`.

However, if I go to another file where `settings` is imported (before the change), and inspect the value of `settings.x`, I don't see that the change took effect, meaning `settings.x` over there holds the old value, and this confuses me.

Could it be because `settings.py` was imported to the other file before the update took place? I thought it shouldn't be the case if I'm doing `import settings` and then accessing `settings.x`

In any case I want it to be able to always take the last value of x, that is updated every once and then in `main.py`.

Comment: `settings.py` itself (the file) is not being changed at all. It doesn't matter if the import happens before the value is changed or not, it's still not going to be able to see it unless the file itself is changed. Instead of structuring things this way, pass the current value of `x` around between the functions/methods that use it.

Comment: @MattDMo thanks for the suggestion but I think passing x around is not the best use case here since of the magnitude of different places x is being used at. But why does the file itself needs to be changed so that the change would take effect?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class out of your settings.
Eg:

```
# Settings.py
class Settings:
    x = {}
    def getSettings(self):
        return self.x
    def setSettings(self, x):
        self.x = x

myAppSettings = Settings()
```

.

```
#someFile.py
from settings import myAppSettings 

def returnSettingsFromSomeFile():
     return myAppSettings.getSettings()
```

.

```
from settings import myAppSettings 
from somefile import returnSettingsFromSomeFile

def returnSettingsFromThisFile():
    return myAppSettings.getSettings()

print(returnSettingsFromThisFile()) # {}
print(returnSettingsFromSomeFile()) # {}

myAppSettings.setSettings({'a': 1})

print(returnSettingsFromThisFile()) # {'a': 1}
print(returnSettingsFromSomeFile()) # {'a': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this solution. Few question:

Why didn't my original solution work? Is it because importing from settings keeps the variables in memory, but then why changes in them (as they're global) not reflected everywhere?

In your solution, why do we need the getter/setter and not just use myAppSettings.x to get/set the value?

In what case would using a Singleton here be a better choice?